# Register application in BlackBerry Messenger platform

Tags: blackberry, sdk

I use the simple of creating and register my own application in BlackBerry Messenger platform from http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25690/Register_your_app_with_the_BBM_Platform_1387557_11.jsp. I put the screen pushing command after set listener part, so I have this code:

platformContext.setListener(platformContextListener);
this.pushScreen(new ApplicationScreen(platformContext));

Where ApplicationScreen is my own screen class:

public class ApplicationScreen extends MainScreen {

```
public ApplicationScreen(BBMPlatformContext platformContext){
    super(DEFAULT_MENU | DEFAULT_CLOSE);
    setTitle("BBM application");
    this.add(new LabelField("Screen of BBM application"));

    if (platformContext.isAccessAllowed()){
        platformContext.getUIService().startBBMChat("Let's chat!");
    } else {
        int error = platformContext.getAccessErrorCode();
        this.add(new LabelField("AccessAllowed: no"));
        this.add(new LabelField(translateAccessStatus(error)));
    }


}

private static String translateAccessStatus(int status) {
    switch (status) {
        case BBMPlatformContext.ACCESS_ALLOWED: return "Allowed";
        case BBMPlatformContext.ACCESS_PENDING_REGISTRATION: return "Registration Pending";
        case BBMPlatformContext.ACCESS_BLOCKED_BY_SERVER: return "Blocked by Server";
        case BBMPlatformContext.ACCESS_BLOCKED_BY_USER: return "Blocked by User";
        case BBMPlatformContext.ACCESS_BLOCKED_DUPLICATE_INSTANCE: return "Blocked duplicate instance";
        default: return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

}

But I always have only AccessAllowed: no; Registration Pending. What does it mean, and what I do not correct? I just need to simple testing application wich can register in BBM and provide me interface to it. Now I have no idea where I am wrong.

Comment: +1 I'm stuck in the same place. Help anyone?

Comment: is that an exception or is it that it always goes into the "else" part?